# datetime->format('c') has two format on two machines

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I have build an application in `php` where I use `datetime` and format it to return a `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` date.
That was on Kubuntu.

I just migrated to mac and now using the same code, it returns the date in this format: 
`2017-01-24T10:59:25+00:00`.

Here is the code:

```
$date = new \DateTime('NOW');
$formatedDate = $date->format('c');
```

Has anyone experienced this? 
My guess is, it is a setting on my computer.

It would be great if I can just change this setting instead of updating my code everywhere I call this function.

(PS: the format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` on production on AWS - think it is a linux box)

Edit - If that changes anything, the application is built on `Zend-Framework2`

Comment: From the manual - `'c' = ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5) ex 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00`

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on these 2 machines?

Comment: the mac version is `5.6.24`. My linux died so I don't know which one it is for sure. I might be able to find out but tonight only :( But I would say 5.5.X